# CSS wrapping text around image in non-floated div container

Tags: html, css

Here's my scenario. `#main_content` div contains a `#nav_leftsidebar` div (floated left) for navigation links, `#bottom_leftsidebar` div (floated left) stacked below `#nav_leftsidebar` (by clearing float left) for other info/links, and a `#page_content` div (no float) to the right of both the `#nav_leftsidebar` div and `#bottom_leftsidebar` div.

I am trying to wrap the text around the image in the top left corner of the page_content div, but when I float: left the image, the image drops below my text and aligns left of the `#bottom_leftsidebar` div.

```css
#main_container {
  width: 983px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
}

#nav_leftsidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 5px 10px 0 0;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-right-color: #C0C0C0;
}

#bottom_leftsidebar {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 5px 10px 0 0;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-right-color: #C0C0C0;
}

#page_content {
  position: relative;
  width: 950px;
  margin: 5px 0 0 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav_leftsidebar">
  <ul class="nav_sidebar">
    <li> Items ... </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="bottom_leftsidebar" style="height: 200px">
  bottom_leftsidebar div
</div>

<div id="page_content">
  <h1>Network Design</h1>
  <img id="Img1" alt="" src="~/images/it_networkdesign.jpg" style="float: left; margin: 0px 5px 5px 0px" runat="server" />
  <p>
    Content ...
  </p>
</div>
```

How can I position the image in the top left corner of the `#page_content` div and wrap the text around the right & bottom sides of the image as well?

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post an image of what is happening now?

Comment: Yes, look at http://dev.acci.com/screenshot2.jpg.  Notice how the image drops below all the text and positions itself next to the #bottom_leftsidebar div.  How can I get the image in the top left corner of the #page_content div and wrap the text at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the two sidebars inside the "page content" div. Also consider placing the image inside the `<p>` tag. Here's what I mean:

```
<div id="page_content">    

<div id="nav_leftsidebar">
        <ul class="nav_sidebar">
            <li> Items ... </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="bottom_leftsidebar" style="height: 200px">
        bottom_leftsidebar div
    </div>


        <h1>Network Design</h1>
        <p><img id="Img1" alt="" src="~/images/it_networkdesign.jpg" style="float: left; margin: 0px 5px 5px 0px" runat="server" />

            Content ...
            </p>

</div>
```

Comment: Putting the two sidebars inside the #page_content div breaks my layout of having the two sidebars stacked on the left on the page content on the right.  Also, putting the image inside the <p> element does not work as well.  Image still positions itself below all of the content text.

Comment: What about doing a page_container div? So you'll have your sidebars stacked to the left, and your main content floated right - all contained in a container, with a clearfix div at the bottom?